# WPF Listbox SelectedItem changing twice (bug?)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, mahapps.metro

I have a really weird issue with my custom WPF ListBox:

```
<Grid Name="root"
      Margin="4"
      Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                  SharedSizeGroup="hccFormStyleLabel" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=Theme}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Content="Theme:">
            </Label>
            <ListBox Grid.Column="1"
                     Name="Theme"
                     SelectionMode="Single"
                     Background="Transparent">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                   IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding IsThemeLight}">
                    <Grid Margin="0 4 4 0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Content" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Ellipse Width="16"
                                     Height="16"
                                     StrokeThickness="1"
                                     Stroke="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"
                                     Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" />
                            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Content="Light"></Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding IsThemeDark}">
                    <Grid Margin="0 4 4 0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Content" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Ellipse Width="16"
                                     Height="16"
                                     StrokeThickness="1"
                                     Stroke="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"
                                     Fill="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}" />
                            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Content="Dark"></Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                  SharedSizeGroup="hccFormStyleLabel"
                                  />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=accentcolors}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Content="Accent:">
            </Label>
            <ListBox Grid.Column="1"
                     Name="accentcolors"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding AccentColors, Mode=OneWay}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveAccent, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     SelectionMode="Single"
                     Background="Transparent">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}}" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0 4 4 0"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Content" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Ellipse Width="16"
                                         Height="16"
                                         Margin="2"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         Fill="{Binding ColorBrush}" />
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This renders a listbox in the following style:

A B C D

E F G H

I J K L

now, whenever I click one of B - K, it "randomly" selects one of the other items and not the one I clicked on.

The weird thing is, when I attach a debugger and step trough all property setters/getters, it all works.
When I run it without the debugger (or do not break) the issue occurs again.

I've put Log.Info statements all over the viewmodel property getters and setters, and it looks like that initially the correct item is selected. But after the initial 'set_ActiveAccent call' it is called again with what seems to me to be a random value. As if WPF detects a second mouse-click on another item.

When I remove the ItemsPanel (WrapPanel) it seems to work, but with a WrapPanel it goes back to this weird behavior.

I ruled out the 'Width' binding (if I remove that, the issue still occurs).

Can anybody tell me what is going on here, or how I can investigate this better?

Edit: Ok... this is getting weirder. when I use my right mouse button to select one of the items, it works as normal. So something weird is happening on 'mouse left click'

edit: I narrowed it down to an issue with 'SharedSizeGroup'. I updated the xaml above to show the full xaml I use.

When I remove SharedSizeGroup='hccFormStyleLabel' (on the ColumnDefinition) everything starts working again. Doesn't really make sense to make....

I WANT to use this shared size group, because in my app I extracted most of the xaml above to a reusable HeaderedContentControl. (for clarity I removed that in my example code).

So to sum up: When I set a SharedSizeGroup, I get weird double (random) click behavior. Without it, it works.

Anything I can do? Maybe there's another nice reusable solution to align my form labels instead of shared size groups?

Comment: Your XAML works perfectly in my test environment. Please have a look at your setter of ActiveAccent whether it gets called several times from your code (triggered by the user).

Comment: It seems the listbox isn't the problem but the xaml around it. I narrowed it down to SharedSizeGroup. See updated xaml and explanation. Still not fixed though

Comment: Hm, even your updated version works perfectly on my machine.

Comment: It's definitely not working here. And it has something to do with the sharedsizegroup. Whenever I remove it, it starts working.

Maybe it's something with MahApps.Metro ThemeManager. I see it does some internal method calling (ie. it calls 'typeof(SystemParameters).GetMethod("InvalidateCache")

Comment: Ok.. when I don't call into MahApps.Metro's ThemeManager, it works as well. I suspect these internal method calls (SystemParameters.InvalidateCache and SystemResources.InvalidateResources) are conflicting with the rendering of the grid.

Comment: ýeah, that's it. I added an answer with an explanation. Ill report this bug to MahApps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what's happening.

As you may have suspected, this UI is for changing the current theme and accent of the application.

I am using MahApps.Metro's ThemeManager to dynamically change the theme and accent of the application.

As it turns out, MahApps ThemeManager calls some internal WPF methods to invalidate system resources and caches (to work around some issues when changing resources dynamically).

This is conflicting with SharedSizeGroup (or layout rendering in general).

For now, I'm using a custom build of MahApps.Metro where i disable this work-around.

I will report this bug to MahApps.

Thanks all for looking into this!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar controls which works as expected. Please have a look.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AccentColors}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccentColor, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Margin="0,0,0,16">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Panel}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlatListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="40" Height="40" Margin="2" >
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="Brush" Color="{Binding}" />
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I narrowed it down to SharedSizeGroup. See updated xaml and explanation.

Comment: I thinks, its with your Binding, may be u r calling your NotityOfPropertyChanged("SelectedItemProperty"); twice